# Knowing the number of parameters of a passed function (erlang)

Tags: erlang

In ERLANG: Assume we have a function f() that takes F1 as inputs where F1 is a function. Is there a way to know the number of input parameters of F1.

I feel somehow there IS a solution, but I am not sure. for instance:

```
 -module(high).
 -compile(export_all).

 f1() -> 1.
 f2(X) -> X. 
 f3(X, Y) -> {X,Y}. 

 run(F) -> io:format("F ~p ~n", [F]).
```

So, is there any way for function run/1 to know information about the passed function [mainly the number of input parameters of the passed function].

Note: Please be informed that this is a theoretical question. 
Note: is the code of apply(fun,[arguments]) available in open-source .. this may hep me I guess.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

erlang:fun_info(Fun,arity).

For example

```
F = fun(A,B) -> A+B end.
#Fun<erl_eval.12.111823515>
3> erlang:fun_info(F,arity).
{arity,2}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `module_info/1` to get info about your module.

> `module_info/1`
>
> The call `module_info(Key)`, where `Key` is an atom, returns a single piece of information about the module.
>
> The following values are allowed for `Key`:
>
> ...
>
> `exports`
> Returns a list of {Name,Arity} tuples with all exported functions in the module.
>
> `functions`
> Returns a list of {Name,Arity} tuples with all functions in the module.

http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/modules.html

---

```
run(F) -> find_value(F,module_info(exports)).

find_value(Key, List) ->
    case lists:keyfind(Key, 1, List) of
        {Key, Result} -> {Key,Result};
        false -> io:format("There is no function called ~w.~n", [Key])
    end.
```