# Erlang trying to evaluate a string

Tags: erlang, evaluation, erlang-shell

I'm trying to dynamically evalutate Erlang terms

Start up Erlang

```
basho-catah% erl
Erlang R16B03 (erts-5.10.4) [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.10.4  (abort with ^G)
```

Create a term

```
1> {a,[b,c,d]}.
{a,[b,c,d]}
```

Try to scan in the same term

```
2> {ok, Tokens, _ } = erl_scan:string("{a,[b,c,d]}").
{ok,[{'{',1},
     {atom,1,a},
     {',',1},
     {'[',1},
     {atom,1,b},
     {',',1},
     {atom,1,c},
     {',',1},
     {atom,1,d},
     {']',1},
     {'}',1}],
    1}


3> Tokens.
[{'{',1},
 {atom,1,a},
 {',',1},
 {'[',1},
 {atom,1,b},
 {',',1},
 {atom,1,c},
 {',',1},
 {atom,1,d},
 {']',1},
 {'}',1}]
```

But it can't parse that tokenized string.

```
4> Foo = erl_parse:parse(Tokens).
{error,{1,erl_parse,["syntax error before: ","'{'"]}}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the wrong function, and there's also a caveat you haven't encountered.

First, the function you *should* be using is `erl_parse:parse_term/1`. I'm not actually able to find documentation for `erl_parse:parse/1`, so I suspect it's deprecated (and most likely used for parsing abstract-syntax trees, not tokens).

Second, for `erl_parse:parse_term/1` to work, you *must* include the terminating dot character in your term. `erl_scan:string/1` will happily convert whatever you give it into tokens, but without the terminator `erl_parse:parse_term/1` expects to receive more.

So, try the following in a shell:

```
{ok, Tokens, _} = erl_scan:string("{a,[b,c,d]}.").
erl_parse:parse_term(Tokens).
```

Comment: `erl_parse:parse/1` is the generic parse function genereated by `yecc` (used to build the parser) which parses exactly what the grammar dictates. Normally you call some defined wrapper functions like `erl_parse:parse_term/1`.

Comment: If only Erlang were statically typed ;-)

Comment: Thank your favourite deity it isn't, it would make code loading very difficult and "static". I belong to the Church of Short Variable Names.