# file:consult without the file part

Tags: erlang

I'm writing an escript that needs as its input a normal proplist :

> script "[{error_string, \"This is broken\"}]"

all I wanna do now is parse arbitrary strings into actual proplists, normally I would write this to a file, and then go on to use file:consult on the file to get the values - that does however seem a little over the top - so my question is, how do I do the same, that is parse the input string into a proplist without sending the the data to a file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Erlang trying to evaluate a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23811143/erlang-trying-to-evaluate-a-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
M1 = "[{error_string, \"This is broken\"}].",
{ok, S1, _} = erl_scan:string(M1),
erl_parse:parse_term(S1).
```

returns

```
{ok,[{error_string,"This is broken"}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do it is to use `erl_eval`, just like in [Odobenus Rosmarus answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26350048/1135337), even if it seems little complicated.  Just have to remember to put `.` at the end of your expression.  You can read a little more on this topic on [Erlang Central Wiki](https://erlangcentral.org/wiki/index.php?title=String_Eval).

But if you are building escript to populate your application with options i would look into full-blown argument parser. One I've used before is https://github.com/jcomellas/getopt . Project is stable, with good enough documentation, and does exactly what is should.  It requires little bit configuration, but created code stays readable.